# How To Trace SOAP Messages In NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans, tcp

Eclipse IDE has a feature by means of which I can monitor SOAP message traffic in TCP/IP console as illustrated in the article: 
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/how-to-trace-soap-message-in-eclipse-ide/

Do we have any such mechanism in NetBeans IDE through which I can intercept my webservice calls and monitor the soap messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved it!! We can use the standalone application: Membrane Monitor. I just followed this tutorial http://membrane-soa.org/jaxws-client-monitor-howto.htm using which I traced soap messages

In the above tutorial, the quickstart guide link which is used to setup a service proxy is not working. Use the following link instead of that to set up a service proxy: http://membrane-soa.org/soap-monitor-guide.htm

As Membrane monitor is a standalone application, it can be used along with netbeans, eclipse or any other ide.